# Проблема с запуском MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

При попытке стартовать службу, выдаёт ошибку.
В системных логах сообщается следующее:

```
SQL Server is terminating because of fatal exception c06d007e. This error may be caused by an unhandled Win32 or C++ exception, or by an access violation encountered during exception handling. Check the SQL error log for any related stack dumps or messages. This exception forces SQL Server to shutdown. To recover from this error, restart the server (unless SQLAgent is configured to auto restart).
```

Кто сталкивался? Что это может быть?

Comment: тут вообще кто - то с SQL Server работает? ))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я работаю. В сообщении советуют посмотреть лог сервера. Логи лежат в каталоге типа `Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG\..`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. После всего причина была в том, что у меня был модифицированный файл shell32.dll. Пришлось вернуть оригинал.
+ ПОЛНАЯ переустановка SQL Сервера. )